# Python sorted() returning weird list: [array([...], dtype=int64), ...]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I'm learning/practicing Python and wrote this simple program

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
randList = rng.integers(200, size=(50, 2)) + 1
sortList = sorted(randList, key=lambda x:x[0])

print(randList)
print(sortList)
```

Generate 50 pairs of random integers between 1 and 200 inclusively, then sort the list into a new list based on the first element

When printing the unsorted list I get

```
[[x y]
 [x y]
  ... ]
```

However when I print the sorted list I get

```
[array([x, y], dtype=int64),
 array([x, y], dtype=int64),
 .......................... ]
```

The list is in fact sorted just as I want, but it's printing all this extra stuff.

Am I doing something wrong? All examples I've found related to the sorted function have no mention of this, and I can't find any explanation why it does it.

I program almost exclusively in C++, so Python is very foreign to me. Please help me understand.

I've tried some stuff with separate lists and sorting by tuples or whatever, but it was difficult to understand and didn't work as expected.

Comment: `randList` is not a `list`, it is a `numpy.ndarray` of dimension 2. `sorted` takes any arbitrary iterable, and sorts it. numpy.ndarray objects are iterable over their first dimension, so in this case, it is being treated as an iterable of "rows". Why are you mixing `numpy`/ and `sorted` here to begin with?

Comment: So please help me understand, how do I convert that 1D array back into a 2D array

Comment: _but it's printing all this extra stuff_ That's because `randList` is a list of numpy arrays.

Comment: The reason it's printing the extra stuff is because when you print a list, it prints the elements using `repr()` rather than `str()`. It's the same reason printing a list of strings shows the quotes, but printing a string by itself doesn't.

Comment: @AlexGraalum *"that 1D array"* -- What do you mean? There isn't any one 1D array. If you're talking about `sortList`, it's a **list** of *multiple* 1D arrays. Instead of converting it back to an array, you can just use `np.sort` like Barmar said to keep it as an array.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried `np.sort()` and it doesn't appear to sort or even change my array in any form.
@juanpa.arrivillaga I'm mixing `numpy` and `sorted` because I have no idea how to use Python correctly. Please see the `I'm learning` part at the top.
@JohnGordon Again, I have no idea what I'm doing. Help me understand here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just NumPy and Python having different iterable types. When you print a 2d NumPy **array**, it knows how to display itself properly. When you print a 2d Python **list**, it knows how to display itself properly. When you use `sorted()` it turns a 2d NumPy array into a vanilla Python list of 1d NumPy arrays. The Python list doesn't know how to print out a good representation of the NumPy sub arrays so it gets sort of messed up.

To fix this you can either [use NumPy to sort the NumPy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
sortList = randList[numpy.argsort(randList[:, 0])]
```

*Note, previously used sort, but did it wrong. This should be correct.*

or you can convert the list that comes out of `sorted()` into a NumPy array:

```
sortList = numpy.array(sorted(randList, key=lambda x:x[0]))
```

or you can fully [convert the NumPy array to a list](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
sortList = sorted(randList.toList(), key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Comment: Thank you Sam. Numpy.sort doesn't seem to work, but converting to a numpy array did.

Comment: @AlexGraalum Sorry, I did the wrong axis. It should be axis 0 because you wanted to sort by the first element. Fixed now. Also, remember to accept if this solved your problem.

Comment: I figured it was axis 0, and I had already tried that before posting my question with no results. I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @AlexGraalum I just ran that code and it worked for me. A key thing to note is that `numpy.sort()` returns a copy of the array it is given after sorting it. So it doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: @SamSpade a copy of the *array*. **Not list**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Very good catch, fixed now.

Comment: `np.sort` doesn't work like `sorted` here. It sorts each column individually. To sort rows by the first element, you can use `randList[randList[:,0].argsort()]`

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for that explanation. I haven't used numpy in a long time. I've updated my answer appropriately.